# Merging 2 classes together

Tags: java, mysql

I would like to merge my Vote4Cash class with my commands class.

My vote4cash class will reward the player for voting when they type the command check. Therefor, I need the vote4cash process to be built into my commands class. I've been trying to do this for a while, it's the most important part of my vote4cash system. If you know how I could merge them together or make them work together please tell me how. I tried using imports, it didn't work out. I didn't code the commands class, someone else did, which makes it harder for me to add the vote4gold process or make them work together.

My Vote4Cash class:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Vote4Cash {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

  Connection con = null;
  Statement st = null;
  Statement stmt = null;
  ResultSet auth = null;
  ResultSet given = null;

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String db = "vote4gold";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String user = "root";
    String pass = "";

  try {
  Class.forName(driver);
  con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, user, pass);
  con.setAutoCommit(false);
  st = con.createStatement();
  stmt = con.createStatement();

  //String give = "SELECT `given` FROM `has_voted` WHERE `ip` LIKE '+thisIp.getHostAddress()'";
        InetAddress thisIp =InetAddress.getLocalHost();
String give = "SELECT `given` FROM `has_voted` " + 
              "WHERE `ip` = '" + thisIp.getHostAddress() + "'";
  given = st.executeQuery(give);

while (given.next()) {
    if (given.getInt("given") > 0) {
        System.out.println("You've already recieved a reward for the last time you voted, but thanks again for voting.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Thanks for voting! You've been rewarded 25m gold! Vote again tomorrow!");
        String sql = "SELECT has_voted (given) Replace('0', '0', '1')";
        int rows = stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE has_voted SET given = 1 WHERE given = 0");
        System.out.println("The given reward column has been set to 1 for the ip address:");
       System.out.println("IP:"+thisIp.getHostAddress());
    }
  }
  } catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e);
  }
  }
}
```

My commands class (Wont fit on here):
http://pastebin.com/GXFLfMX4

Thanks! If you need more details or don't understand something please tell me so I can help you help me. :)

Comment: Your question probably involves a bit too much code for most SO users to examine - I would suggest you try and compose a much more specific question, with the precise errors you encounter.

Comment: Java is a word and not an acronym.

Comment: I can't even begin to merge the classes yet, I tried, I have no idea what to do from where I'm at atm. Therefor, I don't have errors, I just need help figuring out how to actually do this.

Comment: You should first leverage your `Command` class, it has too many [anti patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) like God object and Copy and paste programming. After ordering your ideas, redesign your solution with a simpler and more elegant way.

Comment: If your code is too large to post here, nobody is going to read it; StackOverflow is not a free coding service; and like @akf I would question why you want to do it at all. It does not follow from the fact that one class uses another that 'therefore' they need to be merged; in this case it looks like good design to keep them separate.

Answer (score 1):

To start, I would NOT try to 'merge' the code.  That should never be the solution when you receive code from others.  You should first try to understand how it was meant to be used.

To that end...

For starters,  the `Commands` class is declared to be in:
 `package server.model.players.packets;`

So you will need to import that package.  Further, the methods within the `Commands` class take a `Client` as a parameter.  Therefore, in order to use this class, you would need to be able to instantiate an instance of `Client`.

Which `Client` is that?  Well, looking at the import statements in `Commands`, it appears that it would be `server.model.players.Client`.  You would need access to that class and to be able to create an instance.

Were you given the source for `Commands` or a compile set of classes or a jar?  If the former, you will need to have access to all of the other classes that `Commands` imports in order to compile it.

I suspect that, looking at the verbosity of the `Commands` class, and your desire to treat it like a black box (but still merge it with your class ?!? (which really is just a wrapper for a `main` method)), you are really just looking for a quick solution.  I would start a lot smaller.  Resist the urge to merge.  Try to write a `Commands` class of your own, with a couple simple methods taking classes of your design.  You will end up with a process that you understand and a better experience gained.